# Create a dynamic chart in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table of two columns named 'Days' (in column A) and 'Calories' (in column B) that shows how many calories I eat in that Days.

| Days | Calories |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 355 |
| 2 | 709 |
| 3 | 347 |
| 4 | 578 |
| 5 | 254 |
| .. | .. |
| 30 | 793 |

How can make a dynamic chart in google sheet, Days vs. Calories so that I input period of days in another cells (like $D$1 and $E$1) and make Bar chart in google sheet depend on that days?

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. Please take the the [Tour] and review [ask]  This site is not for training. Read Google's instructions at [Add & edit a chart or graph](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63824).  If you run into problems with your chart, let us know what you tried to do and what didn't work and we would be glad to help.